# To find the center of charge in current waveform

Tags: waves, electric-circuits, electric-current

I have a circuit for which output current waveform has both positive and negative points. Now I want to get a center of the charge for this waveform (means where my net charge is concentrated ?). Is there any formula or theorem to calculate this.

My current waveform has time on $x$ axis and current values at $y$ axis.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE . Please edit your question, adding more details (e.g. the circuit, waveform etc.) and your effort thus far. As it stands right now, no one can make out anything from your question :)